# create temp table that deletes itself when I end my transaction

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres 9.6

I wish to `CREATE temp table` that will drop itself at the end of the transaction. I have been looking through the documentation and am having a hard time locating the answer to this.

Comment: `on commit drop`?

Comment: Will this include rollbacks and end as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

> `ON COMMIT`
>   The behavior of temporary tables at the end of a transaction block can be controlled using ON COMMIT. The three options are:
>   
> ...
>   `DROP`
>   The temporary table will be dropped **at the end of the current transaction block**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

The "end of transaction block" is defined by a `commit` or a `rollback`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```sql
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMP TABLE my_temp(id) ON COMMIT DROP AS VALUES
  ('SOME_ID_1'),
  ('SOME_ID_2'),
  ('SOME_ID_3');

-- put your query that uses the temp-table here
SELECT * FROM nodes
JOIN my_temp ON nodes.id = my_temp.id;

END;
```